# Migrating from XPATH to LINQ, need help?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I am trying to update the part in my application that reads data from XML files. At the moment I am using XPATH but I want to update to LINQ.

For simple XPATH queries that I need to only get 1 value, no problem. but the following method I can not figure out how to use LINQ here. Would be nice if you can give some ideas.

```
    public ContinuityData GetSingleContinuityResult(string pin)
    {
        ContinuityData data;

        data = new ContinuityData();

        data.PinName = pin;

        data.PreVoltage = double.Parse(ztr.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Tests/Test[contains(Name, 'Pre Continuity')]/Groups/Group/Pins/Pin[Number='" + pin + "']/Spots/Spot/VIPair/Voltage").InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        data.PreCurrent = double.Parse(ztr.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Tests/Test[contains(Name, 'Pre Continuity')]/Groups/Group/Pins/Pin[Number='" + pin + "']/Spots/Spot/VIPair/Current").InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        data.PostVoltage = double.Parse(ztr.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Tests/Test[contains(Name, 'Post Continuity')]/Groups/Group/Pins/Pin[Number='" + pin + "']/Spots/Spot/VIPair/Voltage").InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        data.PostCurrent = double.Parse(ztr.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Tests/Test[contains(Name, 'Post Continuity')]/Groups/Group/Pins/Pin[Number='" + pin + "']/Spots/Spot/VIPair/Current").InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return data;
    }
```

Note that `ztr`is a `XmlDocument` instance.

Here is how the XML file looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please provide your xml file structure.

Comment: Done! hope it helps, it is a huge file!

Comment: What program output this?  I see several people on google trying to parse these exact file types...

Comment: It is output of an old electronics measurement instrument which its own software is a big mess. So I think like me everybody tries to make theire own result viewer :D it is called Mk.2

Comment: But if you mean the xml picture up there....it is xMLSpear!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public ContinuityData GetSingleContinuityResult(string pin)
{
    ContinuityData data;

    data = new ContinuityData();

    data.PinName = pin;

    XElement xtr = XElement.Load("path/to/your/xml/file");

    Func<string, string, string, double> getViData =
        (testName, pin, mode) =>
        Convert.ToDouble(
            xtr 
                .Descendants("Test")
                .Where(test => test.Descendants("Name")
                                   .First().Value.Contains(testName))
                .Descendants("Pin")
                .Where(p => p.Descendants("Number")
                                .First().Value == pin)
                .Descendants("VIPair")
                .Descendants(mode)
                .First().Value);

    data.PreVoltage = getViData("Pre Continuity", pin, "Voltage");
    data.PreCurrent = getViData("Pre Continuity", pin, "Current");

    data.PostCurrent = getViData("Post Continuity", pin, "Current");
    data.PostVoltage = getViData("Post Continuity", pin, "Voltage");

    return data;
}
```

If you it trouble understanding this, please do not hesitate to ask!